# Bring .NET winform to front (focus) on Windows 8

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, c#-4.0

I have a .NET 4.5 C# winforms app that, when a barcode scan is detected, is supposed to come to the foreground (in front of all other apps/windows). I'm using this code to accomplish it:

```
if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
this.Activate();
```

This works perfectly on Windows 7 but doesn't work on Windows 8. If my app is only minimized (and was the most recent app to have focus), it does work, with this line:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

But if any other window/app is IN FRONT OF my app when the barcode scan occurs, `this.Activate()` clearly doesn't work on Windows 8.

What is the solution?

Comment: you need to call the `BringToFront()` method.. so `this.BringToFront` should take care of it.

Comment: No, it is Activate().  This is general likely to not succeed, a process cannot shove a window into the user's face.  The rules are not different in Windows 8, they've been the same for many versions.  You are probably using the UI differently.  There is a secret way to cheat, it is [actually included](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyz95fhy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the TopMost property of the form.

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: This is great...but it forces my winform to the front all the time unless it's minimized. The ideal would be for it to be able to be placed in the background behind other things, but when a scan occurs, then it always should come to the front. Any way to achieve that?

Comment: You should look at the API of the bar code scanner, there might be some events that you can change the TopMost from to true/false as needed.